# PHP/Wordpress: Help me understand why the author of the tutorial uses array_keys() followed by array_flip()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm following [this tutorial](https://pippinsplugins.com/custom-database-api-sample-order-class/) but have been struggling to understand a step in the `insert_row()` method. Here is the method in full:

```
// Adds new row to table
public function insert_row($data, $type='') {
    global $wpdb;

    // set defaults
    $data = wp_parse_args( $data, $this->get_column_defaults());

    do_action('add_pre_insert_' . $type, $data);

    // initialise column format array
    $column_formats = $this->get_columns();

    // force fields to lower case
    $data = array_change_key_case($data);

    // remove unknown columns
    $data = array_intersect_key($data, $column_formats);

    // reorder $column_formats to match the order of columns in $data
    $data_keys = array_keys($data);
    $column_formats = array_merge(array_flip($data_keys), $column_formats);

    $wpdb->insert($this->table_name, $data, $column_formats);

    do_action('add_post_insert_'.$type, $wpdb->insert_id, $data);

    return $wpdb->insert_id;
}
```

I cannot understand why the author assigns `array_keys($data)` to `$data_keys` then calls `array_flip($data_keys)` on the next line. What is happening there?

As I understand it, the keys of `$data` and `array_flip($data_keys)` are exactly the same. Though the values of `array_flip($data_keys)` would be `0,1,2,3,4,...` But why? Wouldn't `$column_formats` overwrite those values anyway?

Comment: They don't use `array_keys` followed by `array_flip`, they use `array_keys` followed by `array_merge`, with an `array_flip`.

Comment: I don't know whey they use, but I know what it will do...

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So `array_keys`  gets the keys of an array, so if you have this array

```
['one'=>'foo', 'two'=>'bar']
```

You get this from array keys:

```
[ 0 => 'one', 1=>'two']
```

Now if you flip that you get

```
['one' => 0, 'two' => 1]
```

AS to why, I have no idea.  I would have to look deeper into the code and I would need some actual data that is used here.

You can test it with this bit of code (FYI I did this first bit in my head):

```
$a=['one'=>'foo', 'two'=>'bar'];
var_export($a);
$a = array_keys($a);
var_export($a);
$a = array_flip($a);
var_export($a);
```

Outputs:

```
array (
  'one' => 'foo',
  'two' => 'bar',
)array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
)array (
  'one' => 0,
  'two' => 1,
)
```

You can test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1215beb1ec1ba57af9c1377140b5fde21faf7a1)

Once you add `array_merge` in any keys that exist will be replaced.  Now if it was me just from a conceptual point, assuming you don't want those number in there if a key is missing, I would have used `array_fill_keys` instead of `array_flip`

```
$a=['one'=>'foo', 'two'=>'bar'];
var_export($a);
$a = array_keys($a);
var_export($a);
$a = array_fill_keys($a, '');
var_export($a);
```

Outputs

```
array (
  'one' => 'foo',
  'two' => 'bar',
)array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
)array (
  'one' => '',
  'two' => '',
)
```

As you can see the last array has just an empty string for the value, the previous way if an item is missing you get the number as the left over value.  This way you would get an empty string as the left over value.

See it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca3ee6bdb3aa77cad3d84a06857e01664431dcfb)

But like I said there is no way to know what their intent was without knowing what the data is that this works on.  I am just "assuming" here (to make my point)